# Python - Insert an element to a list only if some specific element exists in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings `a` and I want to compare my list to a specific string `b` and if that string is found in some of the elements of the list, I want to insert another element in the list `a` front of it.

So if I say `b='alice'`, I want to check the whole list against `b` and if any of the elements is `'alice'` I want to add `'amber'` in front of `'alice'`.

So something like this:

```
 a = ['tom', 'alice'. 'chris']
```

if `'alice'` is in `a` than insert `'amber'` before `'alice'`

In the end it would be:

```
a = ['tom', 'amber', 'alice'. 'chris']
```

Comment: aside from the backwards `'a' in 'alice'`, whats stopping you converting your pseudocode into your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a new list.  If you like, rename a to the new list

```
a = ['tom', 'alice', 'chris', 'alice', 'alice', 'bill']
b = 'alice'
to_add = 'amber'
result = []

for i in a:
    if i == b:
        result.append(to_add)
    result.append(i)
```

This gives:

```
>>> result
['tom', 'amber', 'alice', 'chris', 'amber', 'alice', 'amber', 'alice', 'bill']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
a = ['tom', 'alice', 'chris', 'alice', 'alice']
c = 'alice' 

result = list(chain.from_iterable([['amber', i] if i == c else [i] for i in a]))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['tom', 'amber', 'alice', 'chris', 'amber', 'alice', 'amber', 'alice']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['tom', 'alice', 'chris']
b = 'alice'
to_add = 'amber'
if b in a:
    a.insert(a.index(b), to_add)
a
```

Output:

```
['tom', 'amber', 'alice', 'chris']
```

Comment: This will only catch the first instance of 'alice'.  Unclear, but I think the OP is saying there could be more.

Comment: Yes, there will definitely be more instances, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Vesper So un-accept my answer, and use one of the others here.